# In React with flowtype how do I type only certain props and allow any others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm making an input in form and want to type certain props for my input component but allow any others through without typing them - like all the attributes for an input field.

Do I really need to create a type for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an [intersection](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/) type of custom props + any input props:

```
type Props = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number,
} & $Shape<HTMLInputElement>
```

[$Shape](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape) used above:

> Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional.

Answer (score 0):

Flow supports subtype polymorphism. So if you define a type like this

```
type Foo = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
}
```

Any object that has *at least* those fields, will be a valid `Foo`:

```
let foo: Foo = { 
    a: 0,
    b: "hello",
    c: false // this is ok
}
```

However, if you actually need to access those fields then you should make them part of the type.